# How to get the date and the time from XmlGregorianCalendar

Tags: java

i have this code for the date:

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar retrieveXMLGregorianCalendar(Date source)  {
            XMLGregorianCalendar dest = null;
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (source !=null) {
                calendar.setTime(source);
                DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory;
                try {
                    datatypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
                    dest =  datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar
                            .get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
                    dest.setHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
                    dest.setMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                    dest.setSecond(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new SoapFaultException("Date Trasfomation Exception");
                }
            }
            return dest;
        }
```

and this code for the hour:

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar retrieveXMLGregorianCalendarTime(Date source)  {
        XMLGregorianCalendar dest = null;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (source !=null) {
          calendar.setTime(source);
          DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory;
          try {
            datatypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
            dest =  datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendarTime(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar
                .get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            dest.setYear(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            dest.setMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            dest.setDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
          } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
        }
        return dest;
      }
```

And I just want to catch the date like this format (dd/MM/YYYY) and the hour like this (hh:mm:ss). But I don't know how to catch it. I've tried several times, trying to not catching the hours or minutes for the date but my eclipse say that minutes or hours are not set.

Comment: Please be a little more specific -- what do you want ? Do you want to convert a formatted date string to a XMLGregorianCalendar, or convert a XMLGregorianCalendar to a Date object ?

Answer (score 0):

To format Date (to String):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println(sdfDate.format(source));

System.out.println(sdfTime.format(source));

System.out.println(sdfDateTime.format(source));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method returns you `xmlGregorianCalendar`

convert it to `GregorianCalendar` and

finally get the time from `GregorianCalendar` using `getTime()` and format it using `SimpleDateFormat` in `dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss`

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = retrieveXMLGregorianCalendar(new Date());
Date date = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```